# Can a hard poweroff / outage / crash corrupt VMware snapshots?

Tags: filesystems, crash, vmware

Assuming a host system is running virtual machines (in VMware Workstation) and all their data is on a reliable storage (so no data corruption due to hdd failure).

If that host crashes (kernel panic) while a vm is running, files on the virtual filesystem could be corrupted. But there's a snapshot (of the vm), taken before the crash. Is it safe to assume that reverting to the snapshot, the vm will be back in a clean state - or is there any way that this snapshot could have been corrupted by the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

theoretically any file that was open for write, or had its metadata in a write state could be corrupted by a kernel panic, but if the files were not likely being used at the time, they are likely integral.

to ensure this in future, if you are really worried about it, you may want to look into calculating a hash on the snapshots after they are completed, so that you can tell if they are still integral when you go to rollback to them.

snapshots are a pretty good way to store system state, and can be very useful, but they are not a replacement for a traditional backup strategy.

Answer (score 0):

A Panic shouldn't affect data that has already been written to files that are not in active use.

However, disks have large caches and a power-loss could cause that data to be lost.